# Hide content type from the new menu but show in edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

SharePoint Online, I have following 4 site content types
Word Document
Excel document
PowerPoint document
General document

These content types are being used in a document library and "Word Document" is the default content type, When user clicks on "new" menu, all 4 content types are shown.

I don't want to show "General document" in the new menu but I want to show in edit form, I have marked it hidden in the library settings but now it is not visible in the edit form.

Any idea how can I hide content type from the new button but show in edit form?
JavaScript hide is not preferred.

Comment: One thing would to create new forms using Infopath. In this way you can create totally different forms for new, edit and display.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible, I would go for JavaScript solution.

Comment: Or, you could use powershell to hide the content type column in the new item form for the specific list. Works out to. :)
http://mroffice365.com/2012/05/sharepoint-list-show-hide-list-column-using-powershell/